# How to deal with Django Cascade deletion and django-simple-history?

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-simple-history

I'm working on a django project and i'd like to developp an history application to show every changes in my models.
I installed the package *django-simple-history* that seems to be the easier and the most used.

The thing is, that it raises an error when i try to delete an object involved in the *ForeignKey* of a child Model.

Here is an example:

```
class ParentModel(models.Model):
    age = models.IntegerField()
    name= models.CharField(max_length = 30, blank=True)
    history = HistoricalRecords()

class ChildModel(models.Model):
    parent_objects = models.HistoricForeignKey(ParentModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    book = models.CharField(max_length = 20, blank=False)
    history = HistoricalRecords()
```

So i have to tables, and one refers to the other by a *ForeignKey* (i used the package's *HistoricForeignKey* in my code but it's the same).

Then i access to the historic objects like this:

```
from django.apps import apps
apps.get_model("ParentModelHistorical").objects.all()
apps.get_model("ChildrenModelHistorical").objects.all()
```

The problem is when i delete a ParentModel's object. So all the related ChildrenModel's objects are also delted (the CASCADE deletion).

And when i try to access again the historic objects i get this :

```
apps.get_model("ParentModelHistorical").objects.all()  #-> no errors, everything's fine
apps.get_model("ChildrenModelHistorical")..objects.all() #-> ERROR : MyApp.models.parent_object.DoesNotExist: parent_object matching query does not exist.
```

So what i understand is that the historic object of the Child Model is raising an error because it was created after the parent object was deleted. And so it's *foreignKey* attribute links on nothing.

I can’t do without cascading so I hope it’s possible to overcome this error because *django-simple-history* has met all my expectations so far.

Thanks you for your help